# Running libreoffice from php exec()

Tags: php, permissions, exec, libreoffice

I have installed libreoffice headless on a freebsd-server with apache in order to convert documents programmatically (e.g. odt->pdf). It works from the command line! But my goal is to be able to do it from php. This demands that the web-user (www) can run libreoffice. But it cannot.

When running libreoffice as my own user, I get:

```
%libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf Litteraturundervisningogit.doc
javaPathHelper: not found #This should not be a problem, says people on the net.
convert /usr/home/bundsgaard.net/www/jeppe/foredrag/Litteraturundervisningogit.doc ->
 /usr/home/bundsgaard.net/www/jeppe/foredrag/Litteraturundervisningogit.pdf using writer_pdf_Export
%
```

If I try the same command as root, it does not work. The same is the problem with the www-user from php:

```
sp# libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf Litteraturundervisningogit.doc
javaPathHelper: not found
sp#
```

The problem is that I do not get any information from libreoffice, thus I don't know why libreoffice does not want to run as other users than my own.

My question is: How do I give the www-user permission to run libreoffice via exec() in php?

Comment: Is it just a PATH issue? What is in their respective `$PATH`'s?

Comment: You tested by command line with root user, `%sudo php program.php`, that as client have permission?

Answer (score 17):

I managed to fix this issue with a quick `export HOME=/tmp` before running the convert command, this gives libreoffice somewhere writable to work it's magic.

Comment: That is very smart... You probably saved me a lot of time. Thanks.

Comment: This solves hanging conversions from PHP for me, but can you tell me what this exactly does? Why does this solve hanging conversions?

Comment: Libreoffice writes shadow/temporary/hidden files to the user's (the user running PHP, normally apache or http or www-data) home directory. The user running PHP from a webserver (not from CLI) never normally has a home directory, so the $HOME env variable will be blank or not set and libreoffice cannot write to /. So setting this explicitly to tmp gives libreoffice a bit of space with permission to write. HTH

Answer (score 3):

Not strictly an answer, but rather than using PHP's exec, you might consider using [PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05), a PHP5 module that provides access to the OpenOffice.org UNO Programming API.

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at this blog post?

http://geekswithblogs.net/robertphyatt/archive/2011/11/19/converting-.docx-to-pdf-or-.doc-to-pdf-or-.doc.aspx

Comment: I am a little biased, for obvious reasons, but I think this is the best solution :)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

Make sure you have installed java RE, for example in ubuntu:

```
apt-get install default-jre
```

First, find the location of your libreoffice

```
$ which libreoffice
/usr/bin/libreoffice
```

Include the folder location in the PATH, and also set the HOME var by adding these lines:

```
putenv('PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin');
putenv('HOME=/tmp'); 
system("libreoffice .....
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and yes (thanks Wrikken) after prepending `/usr/local/sbin` to the PATH environment variable I was able to run libreoffice as www-data under apache.

Comment: @nikyspag Sir, please could you share your code with me.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recomend put config path first you run exec() or shell_exec();

IE:

```
// Vars
putenv('PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin');
putenv('HOME=' . $outputdir);
```

$outputdir = chmod 777 And the same forlder from libreoffice command "--outdir"

Answer (score 1):

It is working for me.

You can convert docx to HTML by using libreoffice, You need to give proper permission output directory

```
exec("export HOME='/var/www/html/wp/wp-content/uploads/' && /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless   --convert-to html --outdir '/var/www/html/wp/wp-content/uploads/' /var/www/html/wp/wp-content/uploads/demo.docx");
```

Answer (score 0):

About  [Universal Network Objects (UNO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Network_Objects), there are some "plug-and-play" final-user tools, see [Docvert](http://holloway.co.nz/docvert/) and  *JODConverter* ([jODconverter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jodconverter) and [pyODconverter](https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter)). All of then can be called as web-service or exec by PHP.