# shell_exec error with libreoffice

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec, libreoffice

I try to exec the following command with php:

```
shell_exec('libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.doc 2>&1');
```

and I get the following error:

```
[Java framework] Error in function createSettingsDocument (elements.cxx).
javaldx failed!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
```

This works:

```
exec('touch test1');
```

And on command line this also works (pdf is generated):

```
$ libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf doc1.doc
```

is that a permission problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: I used shell_exec instead of exec and now I get an error. I updated question

Comment: updated title and added libreoffice tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to set an output path like:

```
exec('libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf test.doc --outdir /YOUR/PATH/');
```

or you try something like this for your webserver user:

```
sudo -u www-data -c "export HOME=/tmp"
```

found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10193459/5431346